# Generate slug field in existing table

Tags: python, django

I have table with data. Is it possible slug field automatically generated on existing table? Or is there any other alternative? Thanks
Here is my table

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using the [`slugify`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slugify) template filter, you can write a script, or loop through the objects in the shell.

```
>>> from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
>>> for obj in MyModel.objects.all():
...     obj.slug = slugify(obj.title)
...     obj.save()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The above snippet would set slugs for all existing records in the database. If you want to update the slug for all records added in future, then you could override the save method - see @Tom's answer for example.

Comment: @thanks But getting error. `NameError: name 'instance' is not defined`

Comment: Thanks Alasdair, using AutoSlugField from autoslug with your command save my time

Answer (score 4):

I have a convenience model I use in all projects for these kinds of things. I think it's a good example of how to do what you want.

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify


class NameAndSlug(models.Model):
    '''
    convenience model for things that are just names
    '''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Slugify name if it doesn't exist. IMPORTANT: doesn't check to see
        if slug is a dupe!
        """
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(NameAndSlug, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: thanks. Why I'm getting this error? `    def __unicode__(self):
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

Comment: Check your whitespace. Do you have too many or too few spaces? Are you mixing tabs and spaces?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in MySQL like so (substitute the name of your table for "tableName"):

```
UPDATE `tableName` SET `slug`=LOWER(REPLACE( `title` , ' ' , '-' ));
```

This changes titles like "This Is A Title" to slugs like "this-is-a-title".

**EDIT** To handle parentheses and remove double spaces use:

```
UPDATE `tableName` SET `slug`=LOWER( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( `title` , '(' , '' ) , ')' , '' ) , '  ' , ' ' ) , ' ' , '-' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks But my title also has `parentheses`

Comment: I edited to clean out parentheses as well.  You can continue nesting REPLACE() until you've handled all of your target characters.

Comment: This is awesome but i want slug by two columns like title and category. then what will be the query.

Comment: I got solution

UPDATE `products` SET `slug`=LOWER( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(CONCAT(`title`, '-', `category`) , '(' , '' ) , ')' , '' ) , '  ' , ' ' ) , ' ' , '-' ) );